# Hyperledger Fabric channel queryInfo throws access denied error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to query channel info with node sdk (https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html - channel.queryInfo()).

I have two networks setup (Network setup not done by me. So, I don't know what are the differences).
In one network, I'm able to query successfully.
In the other one, I'm getting this error:

> Error: access denied for [GetChainInfo][ ]: [failed
> evaluating policy on signed data during check policy
> [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [Failed to reach implicit threshold of
> 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining]]

But, when I call with useAdmin=true, i.e., channel.queryInfo(undefined, true) it works. I'm wondering what could cause such error in one network and not in the other. Is there any params that is passed while creating the channel to allow/disallow non admins from querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACL of a channel has the default field of

```
        #ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
```

And the Reader of each org is defined in the configtx.yaml like

```
          Policies: &org1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('org1.example.com.member')"
```

It looks like here is where your problem might be. Make sure Readers is `.member` not `.admin` of the OrgMSP.